# LOCAL SERVICE displayed as a TFS user

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I installed TFS 2010 on Windows 7.

In the **TFS users list** (when creating a new work item) I can see not only real TFS users, but also the **"LOCAL SERVICE" user** - which I surely would not like to appear in the list.

What can be done about that? How can this user be removed?